# sonyのspresense用GNSSアドオンボードでColdStartが正常に動作しない。（Arduino環境）

Tags: spresense

Arduino環境で新たに追加されたGNSSアドオンボードを動作させています。サンプルスケッチでは通常通り動作したので、シリアル入力から測位開始（Cold|HotStart）、Stopを切り替えられるようにして見たのですが、一度測位に成功した後Stopし再度ColdStartでStartしても即時刻もStop時からの継続のような正しいと思われる時刻が表示されるし、測位は10秒以内で成功してしまうため、衛星軌道情報もクリアされていない様に思えます。APIにあるGnssDebugを有効にしてDebug情報を表示してみましたが、ModeはColdStartと表示されているためコードは間違っていないでと考えています。GNSSアドオンボードのColdStartは一般的なColdStartとは違うのでしょうか。

Comment: あなたのいう正常に動作するというのはどういう状態のことを言うんでしょうか

Comment: 質問ありがとうございます。今回はスタート条件についてのテストでしたので、COLD_STARTを指定してstartを実行しているので通常は時刻情報や衛星軌道情報は存在しない（Default）でstartすると考えました。今回はCOLD_STARTでstartしても数秒で測位成功しているため設定条件でstart出来ていないのかなと考えた次第です。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

GNSS Add-onボードでは、スタートモードの指定に依らず、
高速に測位するためにホットスタート可能な条件を
自動的に判断してホットスタートで測位を行う仕様になっています。

Comment: 公式からのご回答光栄です。自動でstartmodeが選択されると言うことですがArduino開発環境以外含めて故意にColdStartは設定出来ないのでしょうか？またこれはArduino環境ではないGitにあるCのAddOnボード用サンプルコードでもStartModeの設定などは無く有るのはBuiltonGnssボードサンプルの様にStartmodeや利用衛星選択等は無く測位間隔位等最低限設定しか記述されていません。実際AddOnBoardではStartmodeと同様に利用衛星選択を設定しQueryApiでは例えばGPSのみ有効とReplyされるのにそれ以外の衛星（GlonassやQZSS,Beidou）がサーチされています。もしかして利用衛星も自動であり個別に制御出来ないのでしょうか。今後のVersionup等での対応など予定があれば教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご理解の通りで、スタートモードはHotStart固定、衛星選択はL1/L5含めた全衛星固定の仕様になっております。
参考: <https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_プログラム解説_20>
今後のバージョンアップで、みちびき災危通報対応などを予定していますが、上記仕様に関しては特に更新の予定はございません。